# facebook login PHP API integration with a custom website

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

I am trying to create a login page to my custom website using the facebook PHP API, basically the website will ask the users to login with their facebook credentials and retrieve their basic profile information; that is the second part though. I am having problems in getting the login to work. Please see below code that i am using. I have already created an app on developers.facebook.com and i am using the app id and the secret in the php code. All i get is a blank page. Can someone please assist me on this? I am running IIS on Win XP with PHP 5.3.27.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test FB Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 

include 'libs/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => '5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx5',
'secret' => '9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx26',
'cookie' => true
));
$session = $facebook->getSession();
$me = null;

if($session)
{
try
{
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
}
catch(FacebookApiException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
}
if($me)
{
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
echo "<a href='$logoutUrl'>Logout</a>"
}
else
{
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
echo "<a href='$loginUrl'>Login</a>"
}
 ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What version of the PHP SDK are you using? `getSession()` was in the old old old old SDKs... I'd recommend updating first and foremost.

Comment: Once you have updated the SDK and the relevant code using it, see if the same problem persists.

Comment: I am using the latest version of php sdk downloaded from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/.               Would it be possible to share a sample working code? Thanks....

Comment: There is no getSession method in the new SDK. The documentation contains all examples you need.. It's the link you already posted in your comment..